# mysql query in zend format

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I have the following sql statement

```
SELECT a.* FROM accounts a 
JOIN account_friends f 
ON f.friend_id = a.id 
WHERE f.account_id = 12;
```

which results in a something like

```
id    username    password    email
14      test        test       ..
15      test2       test       ..
```

What i can't to do is convert this to a zend statement. I tried this

```
    $accFriendTable = new Default_Model_DbTable_AccountFriends();
    $query = $accFriendTable->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $query->from(array('a' => 'accounts'), array('a.*'));
    $query->join(array('f' => 'account_friends'), 'f.friend_id = a.id');
    $query->where('f.account_id = ?', $this->_id);
    $friendsList = $accFriendTable->fetchAll($query);
```

which results in selecting BOTH the columns from the accounts table and the account_friends table, something like this

```
id    username    password    email    account_id    friend_id
1      test        test        ..         12             14
2      test2       test        ..         12             15
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the array of columns you want from joined tables as by default it will bring all from them.

And If you do not want any column just pass `NULL` like below,

```
$query->join(array('f' => 'account_friends'), 'f.friend_id = a.id',NULL);
```

Comment: Yep that did the job. Thank's a lot! :)

Comment: @Systemfreak - Pleasure is all mine :) Happy Coding !!